# How to estimate the power produced by this small U-238 check source?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

I got this sealed check source to test my pancake detector (tube model is LND 7317). But I'm wondering if it's worth trying to collect some of the tiny amount of power it's producing as a fun home experiment.

[image: U-238 check source]

If somehow the image isn't displayed, it reads:

- U-238
- 10μCi
- 4.468E9(6)Yrs
- Radioactive Material
- Feb 2018
- Spectrum Techniques
- USNRC & State License Exempt Quantity

When the source touches the plastic grid (which is on top of another aluminum grid): the labeled side gives about 210 CPM; the other side gives about 12k CPM; background is about 55 CPM.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 µCi is 370000 becquerels. That's the number of decays per second. U238 decay makes a 4.3 Mev alpha. Multiplying and converting to SI, I get 0.25 microwatts. There are more decays in the chain: here the important ones are the two betas leading to long-lived U234. Adding in their contribution is a more elaborate calculation, but won't change the result by a factor of 2. So, the power is pretty small.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but it's probably 370000 instead of 270000.

Comment: @spot Yes. Fixed. Unreliable fingers...